# How to manually commit offsets on Kafka source module on getting acknowledgment from Kafka sink module in Spring XD?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-xd, spring-kafka

In the XD stream, messages are consumed from a Kafka topic through a source module, and then sent to a sink Kafka module. The reason behind developing the custom source and sink Kafka modules is that I want to update the offsets from source module only when I get acknowledgement from the sink module downstream, on successfully sent messages.

I am using Spring Integration Kafka 2.0.1.RELEASE and Spring Kafka 1.0.3.RELEASE with topics in Kafka 0.10.0.0 environment.  I have tried the following:

**Source Module Configuration:**

```
@Configuration
public class ModuleConfiguration {

    @Value("${topic}")
    private String topic;

    @Value("${brokerList}")
    private String brokerAddress;

    @Bean
    public SubscribableChannel output() {
        DirectChannel output = new DirectChannel();
        return output;
    }

    @Autowired
    TopicPartitionInitialOffset topicPartition;

    @Bean
    public TopicPartitionInitialOffset topicPartition(){
        return new TopicPartitionInitialOffset(this.topic, 0, (long) 0);    
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container() throws Exception {
        ContainerProperties containerProps = new ContainerProperties(topicPartition);
        containerProps.setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL);
        KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, String> kafkaMessageListenerContainer = new KafkaMessageListenerContainer<>(consumerFactory(),containerProps);
        return kafkaMessageListenerContainer;
    }
    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, this.brokerAddress);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "test-consumer-group");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 15000);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String,String> consumerFactory =  new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
        return consumerFactory;
    }
}
```

**Source Module: InboundKafkaMessageDrivenAdapter**

```
@MessageEndpoint
@Import(ModuleConfiguration.class)
public class InboundKafkaMessageDrivenAdapter {

    @Autowired
    KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container;

    @Autowired
    SubscribableChannel output;

    @Bean
    public KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter<String, String> adapter(KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container) {
        KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter<String, String> kafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter = new KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter<>(container);
        kafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.setOutputChannel(output);
        return kafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter;
    }
}
```

**Sink Module: Configuration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class ModuleConfiguration {

    @Value("${topic}")
    private String topic;

    @Value("${brokerList}")
    private String brokerAddress;

    @Bean
    public KafkaProducerMessageHandler<String,String> handler() throws Exception {
        KafkaProducerMessageHandler<String, String> handler = new KafkaProducerMessageHandler<>(kafkaTemplate());
        handler.setTopicExpression(new LiteralExpression(this.topic));
        return handler;
    }

    @Bean
    public SubscribableChannel input() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, this.brokerAddress);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, 0);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, 16384);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, 1);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BUFFER_MEMORY_CONFIG, 33554432);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(props);
    }
}
```

**Sink Module: SinkActivator**

```
@Import(ModuleConfiguration.class)
@MessageEndpoint
public class SinkActivator {

    @Autowired
    KafkaProducerMessageHandler<String,String> handler;

    @Autowired
    SubscribableChannel input;

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "input")
    public void sendMessage(Message<?> msg) throws Exception{
            Acknowledgment acknowledgment = msg.getHeaders().get(KafkaHeaders.ACKNOWLEDGMENT, Acknowledgment.class);
            handler.handleMessage(msg);
            acknowledgment.acknowledge();
            }
}
```

The source is successful in receiving the messages and sending them to the sink, however when I try to get the Acknowledgment in the sink:

> Acknowledgment acknowledgment = msg.getHeaders().get(KafkaHeaders.ACKNOWLEDGMENT, Acknowledgment.class);

The following exception is thrown:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Incorrect type specified for header 'kafka_acknowledgment'. Expected [interface org.springframework.kafka.support.Acknowledgment] but actual type is [class org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer$ConsumerAcknowledgment]

In the source code for spring-integration-kafka-2.0.1.RELEASE the class KafkaMessageListenerContainer when AckMode=MANUAL a kafka_acknowledgment header is added to the message, however the type is an inner static class of ConsumerAcknowldgment.

So how do I get the Acknowledgment from the sink module on the message sent from the source?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using the local transport, you can't do that, the `Acknowledgment` is a "live" object and can't be sent over the wire to another module.

If you are using the local transport it will work, but you will have class loader problems because each module runs in its own class loader and the `Acknowledgment` interfaces are difference instances of the class.

You would have to move spring-integration-kafka and spring-kafka to the xd/lib folder so the classes are loaded from a common classloader.

Comment: Quick question: We are using xd with redis transport {default} so our modules deployed on xd communicate through redis queues.  Would that be considered local transport?  I believe so but just wanted to confirm with you.

Comment: No; local means the sink runs on the same thread as the source - you can't transport a "live" `Acknowledgment` object over Redis.The acknowledment has state related to the source's consumer so you can't "remotely" acknowlwdge like that. And local only works with  single node.

Comment: One more follow up question:

So in our stream do you have any suggestions on architecture patterns where our stream in XD  the Kafka source module will only acknowledge when the message has successfully sent from the sink module.  This is a non-negotiable solution given to us for all the streams on our XD platform.  We would really appreciate a suggestion or workaround for the solution.  Thanks again.

Comment: There really is no out of the box solution; you would have to provide some kind of back-door acknowledgment back to the source (perhaps via another redis list). The source would have to keep a reference to the ack object and ack it when the confirmation arrives. Welcome to microservices :) You also have to be careful about multi-threading - you might ack a later message while an earlier one failed and the later offset will effectively ack the failed one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! As per you suggestion to move to microservices, could you hint towards how we would leverage spring cloud data flow, cloud foundry, or other spring cloud features to achieve a stream whose source only acknowledges on successful sink message processing? We have gone through some fundamentals, but we don't have implementation experience so its difficult for us to visualize a solution so any architecture design/guidance is much appreciated.  I'm confident that this case would be important one for a lot of enterprises.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I would't do it that way. I would use RabbitMQ instead of Redis for the transport; that way you can be sure the message is secured in rabbit so it's ok to update the offset in kafka at that time. If you **must** do it that way, consider moving from XD to spring-cloud-stream and use an [Aggregated Application](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/1.0.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#_aggregation) so that the sink runs on the source thread. spring-cloud-stream/spring-cloud-dataflow are the next-generation projects for XD.

Comment: Trying to maintain state and feedback from the sink is fraught with difficulty.

Comment: If your recommendation is not to rely on sink acknowledgement to update kafka offsets, how would do you suggest we solve the problem where we have a stream that consumes from a kafka topic and after some processing pushes to a different kafka topic and ensure when a processing service (rest client in our case) goes down we pause the stream and the stream gets back online automatically and there is no data loss?  Basically automated at most once delivery mechanism that's robust.